# Learn Python the Hard Way Exercise 5 Extra Credit 1: "Change all the variables so there isn't the my_ in front."

Tags: python

I can't figure out how Zed got rid of every instance of 'My_' automatically in the Extra Credit 1 section of Chapter 5.

I have Googled a few things but most of the suggestions seem to use code that I reckon would be too advanced for this early in the book and I am sure Zed wouldn't have expected something that complicated - there must be a simpler solution.

Thanks, J

Comment: Please include all necessary information here so we don't have to lookup the exercise.

Comment: I looked up the exercise, and I believe the intent is for you to *edit* the code manually to remove the prefixes.  It's trying to teach you how variable names are meaningless strings *to the computer*, so you can rename them and it doesn't change what the program does (and therefore you should pick them so they are meaningful *to human readers*).

Answer (score 1):

Use the editors Find and Replace feature
ctrl + f or cmd + f
then "replace"

In the 'Find what' enter "my_"
In 'Replace with' enter nothing: ""

Click on "replace all"